# quicksort algorithm implementaion in c

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

This is the implementation of quicksort algorithm in c,here for the given input my program is giving output as `4 5 -343534 1`,i am new to programming ,Please it would be really helpful if you can point out my error

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int partition(int* A, int start, int end) {
        int pivot = A[end];
        int pindex = start;
        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
            if (A[i] <= pivot) {
                int temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[pindex];
                A[pindex] = temp;
                pindex = pindex + 1;
            }
        }
        int temp = A[end];
        A[end] = A[pindex];
        A[pindex] = temp;
        return pindex;
    }
    void quicksort(int* A, int start, int end) {
        if (start < end) {
            int pindex = partition(A, start, end);
            quicksort(A, start, pindex - 1);
            quicksort(A, pindex+1, end);
        }
    }
    int main() {
        int* a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
        a[0] = 1;
        a[1] = 5;
        a[2] = 4;
        a[3] = 2;
        quicksort(a, 0, 3);
        printf("%d %d %d %d", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: I'd argue that one problem is that you don't use the standard [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) function. But if this is a school (or similar) assignment then that's natural.

Comment: As for problems with the code you show, I recommend that you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Try "executing" the code on paper.

Comment: Havent written C in a long time, but if i remember correctly then pointer mallocated arryas work bit differently. http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syllabus/2-C-adv-data/dyn-array.html This might give you some insight to what is wrong.

Comment: Im not sure, you should debug this by yourself, but in my opinion `pindex` in `void quicksort(...)` could point to edge of `A`, and in that case you will fire recursive `void quicksort(...)` with `start` index greater than `end` index, or `end` less than `start`

Comment: A simple debugging technique mentioned only in a comment to the blog I linked to before, is to print all variables. For example, in the `partition` function add as the first line `printf("partition(..., %d, %d)\n", start, end);` to see the values of `start` and `end`. That way you can quite quickly see if one of them happens to be out of bounds (which is what probably happens here).

Comment: one obvious typo : `for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {` should be `for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {`

Comment: Just fyi, this is *much* easier when you use pointer arithmetic and a single magnitude argument rather than the same base pointer and a start/stop window. The error Sander mentioned (which is core to your issue) would have been avoided entirely had you done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the `partition` function:

The `i` variable should start a `start` not at 0:

```
int partition(int* A, int start, int end) 
{
    int pivot = A[end];
    int pindex = start;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (A[i] <= pivot) {
            int temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[pindex];
            A[pindex] = temp;
            pindex = pindex + 1;
        }
    }
    int temp = A[end];
    A[end] = A[pindex];
    A[pindex] = temp;
    return pindex;
}
```

Your code can be improved in a way: define a `swap` function to avoid repeating yourself:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void print_array(int *A, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%d ", A[i]);

    puts("");
}
void swap(int *A, int i, int j)
{
    if (i == j)
        return ;

    int temp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = temp;
}

int partition(int* A, int start, int end) {
    int pivot = A[end];
    int pindex = start;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (A[i] <= pivot) {
            swap(A, i, pindex);
            pindex = pindex + 1;
        }
    }
    swap(A, end, pindex);

    return pindex;
}
void quicksort(int* A, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int pindex = partition(A, start, end);
        quicksort(A, start, pindex - 1);
        quicksort(A, pindex+1, end);
    }

}
int main() {
    int i, size = 32;
    int* a = malloc(sizeof * a * size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        a[i] = rand()%100;

    print_array(a, size);

    quicksort(a, 0, size-1);

    print_array(a, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Gives:

```
83 86 77 15 93 35 86 92 49 21 62 27 90 59 63 26 40 26 72 36 11 68 67 29 82 30 62 23 67 35 29 2 
2 11 15 21 23 26 26 27 29 29 30 35 35 36 40 49 59 62 62 63 67 67 68 72 77 82 83 86 86 90 92 93
```