# merge sort algorithm in c

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

This is the implementaion of merge sort in c for given input `1 5 4 2` i am getting output as `1 2 5 4` Please it would be really helpful tomorrow is my sem end exam  Please help 
I try my best to debug many times but i was unable to find the error becuse everything  was going in recursion
It will be ok if you can tell my error Thanks in advance

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void merge(int* A, int* left, int* right, int nl, int nr) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < nl&&j < nr) {
        if (left[i] < right[j]) {
            A[i] = left[j];
            i++;
            j++;

        }
        else {
            A[i] = right[k];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    while (j < nl) {
        A[i] = left[j];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    while (k < nr) {
        A[i] = right[k];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
}
void mergesort(int* A, int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    int mid = n / 2;
    int* left = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    int* right = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
        left[i] = A[i];
    }
    for (int i = mid; i < n; i++) {
        right[i - mid] = A[i];
    }
    mergesort(left, mid);
    mergesort(right, n - mid);
    merge(A, left, right, mid, n - mid);
}


int main() {
    int* a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 5;
    a[2] = 4;
    a[3] = 2;
    //quicksort(a,0,3);
    mergesort(a, 4);
    printf("%d %d %d %d", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
}
```

Comment: Besides using mergesort instead, this is really no different from [your quicksort question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53536033/quicksort-algorithm-implementaion-in-c).  Debugging is the key IMO, still. Besides, you have quite a lot of *memory leaks* in your code.

Comment: Please sorting chapter is coming its 11 pm in india tomorow morning i have exam
Please help me

Comment: You messed up your `i,j,k` indexes. Start by giving them meaningful names (such as done, ll, rr ...)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: In short, make it *easy* for us to help you.  Follow good programming practices, starting with meaningful variable names.  Learn basic debugging: you've given us no trace of the invalid execution.  Also, note the charter of this site -- in particular, your time crunch is off topic.

Comment: @Prune Thanks sir I am new to programming ,I will keep these things in mind while coding

Comment: We're *all* new to programming in many respects.  The immediate problem here is that the level of help you need is simply not a great match for Stack Overflow -- but you're *close*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement merge sort from "The Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen and Co](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056912/how-to-implement-merge-sort-from-the-introduction-to-algorithms-by-cormen-and)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some bugs. Just update your `merge()` function. There are some points:

- use `i` as the index for `left` array.
- use `j` as the index for `right` array.
- use `k` as the index for `A` array to assign sorted values.
- when `left[i] < right[j]` then assign `A[k] = left[i]` and increment `k` and `i`, you can write this as `A[k++] = left[i++];`.
- else or `left[i] >= right[j]` then assign `A[k] = right[j]` and increment `k` and `j`, you can write this as `A[k++] = right[j++];`.
- Also use `free()` to release the memory allocated by `malloc()`.
- every time you don't need the size of `left` and `right` as `4`. Update them as `mid` and `n-mid` respecfully.

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  void merge(int* A, int* left, int* right, int nl, int nr) {
      int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
      while (i < nl&&j < nr) {
          if (left[i] < right[j]) {
              A[k++] = left[i++];
          }
          else {
              A[k++] = right[j++];
          }
      }
      while (i < nl) {
          A[k++] = left[i++];
      }
      while (j < nr) {
          A[k++] = right[j++];
      }
  }
  void mergesort(int* A, int n) {
      if (n < 2)
          return;
      int mid = n / 2;
      int* left = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * mid);
      int* right = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n - mid));
      for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
          left[i] = A[i];
      }
      for (int i = mid; i < n; i++) {
          right[i - mid] = A[i];
      }
      mergesort(left, mid);
      mergesort(right, n - mid);
      merge(A, left, right, mid, n - mid);

      free(left);
      free(right);
  }


  int main() {
      int* a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
      a[0] = 1;
      a[1] = 5;
      a[2] = 4;
      a[3] = 2;
      //quicksort(a,0,3);
      mergesort(a, 4);
      printf("%d %d %d %d", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

      free(a);

      return 0;
  }
  ```

OutPut:

```
1 2 4 5
```

Comment: Ok, I am on it.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Good fix.  Minor: Code could do 1 allocation: `int* left = malloc(sizeof *left * n); int *right = left + mid; .... free(left);`, yet that gets away from OP's approach.

Comment: yeah that is right